# Flat File to SOAP XML

Tags: java, xml, soap

I have never worked with XML and SOAP envelopes. I am trying to write a generic algorithm to read a flat file and to write the details into a SOAP like XML file. I was thinking of the following approach but want to know if there would be a better approach to do it.

1. Create a file containing the sample XML envelope with variables instead of the actual values
2. Create a properties file which contains a mapping between the variables and the index of the column (containing value for this variable) in the flat file.
3. Read the Flat file line by line in Java Code. Convert the line to an ArrayList based on the columns in the line
4. For each line, I read the sample XML envelope as defined in Step 1 above. I replace the variables in the XML string with the values from the arraylist based on the associated variable index.
5. Write the XML to a file.

I can write the xml file by javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory but that would make the mapping complex and would probably take more time to execute.

Any suggestions on the right approach to achieve this?

Comment: This utility might be interesting: https://github.com/skjolber/mockito-soap-cxf 
I illustrates amoung other things that working with SOAP is pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

Proper approach is to use available/standard frameworks (i.e. JAXB or others). Depends on what is a purpose of your SOAP XML:

- If it is to use in WebService - create a WSDL (to be used by Webservice framework like CXF)
- Then create corresponding Java classes.
  You have two options:

  1. Up-down (easier way): create XSD schema(s) for your XML, then generate your Java classes with JAXB it is xjc compiler and bunch of tools or maven plugins to run it. like wsdl2java, wsimport and so, and so... (if WSDL is in use) or JAXB maven plugins to generate Java classes out of XSD dierxtly
  2. down-up: Create Java classes and annotate them with proper JAXB annotations

That's it. You will set appropriate properties in Java classes.

Again, if it is about webservice webservice implementation (i.e. CXF) will do the rest to get actual SOAP. If you need just an XML (like a file), then you can marshal Java classes to XML by JAXBContext.

It may sound like a long way, but from code prospective it is not complex. Biggest point is to make Java classes properly (and with top-down approach it is only about make proper XSD (and WSDL if needed).